# Aliasing bounds on associated types of traits

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to make a type alias for a group of traits with associated types. However, my alias works in the opposite way, i.e., it requires the bounds to be satisfied wherever it's used.

A minimized example similar to the situation is as follows. I want to create an alias for the trait `Foo` whenever its type `A` can be created from a `u8`:

```rust
trait Foo {
    type A;

    fn foo(&self, a: Self::A);
}

trait Alias: Foo
where
    <Self as Foo>::A: From<u8>,
{
}

impl<T> Alias for T
where
    T: Foo,
    <T as Foo>::A: From<u8>,
{
}
```

When I want to use this alias in the function `test:

```rust
fn test<T: Alias>(x: &T, y: u8) {
    x.foo(y.into());
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as Foo>::A: From<u8>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:20:12
   |
20 | fn test<T: Alias>(x: &T, y: u8) {
   |            ^^^^^ the trait `From<u8>` is not implemented for `<T as Foo>::A`
   |
note: required by a bound in `Alias`
  --> src/lib.rs:9:23
   |
7  | trait Alias: Foo
   |       ----- required by a bound in this trait
8  | where
9  |     <Self as Foo>::A: From<u8>,
   |                       ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Alias`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
   |
20 | fn test<T: Alias>(x: &T, y: u8) where <T as Foo>::A: From<u8> {
   |                                 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

that means I should add the constraint `<T as Foo>::A: From<u8>` as well, which I want to avoid.

Which part I'm doing wrong? If it is a limitation in the compiler, is there any way to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: The problem is that bounds on the trait declaration are for the implementor, not the consumer.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, but this technique works for regular trait aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you also make a type in the new trait.

```rs
trait Alias: Foo {
    type AliasA: From<u8>;
}

impl<T> Alias for T
where
    T: Foo,
    <T as Foo>::A: From<u8>,
{
    type AliasA = T::A;
}
```

Then just replace any usage of `T::A` with `T::AliasA`.

Comment: It looks like it should be: `trait Alias: Foo<A = <Self as Alias>::AliasA>`.